# tabs changed to spaces when copy & pasting

Tags: python3, putty

I am editing a python script in a putty terminal.  A copy and paste causes tabs to be replaced with spaces, even in the same terminal, which causes problems.  Is this putty behavior? Nano behavior?  Something in windows?  I could mark and copy since I am using nano, but eventually the revised script changes need to be pasted back into the Linux system I created the script on. That system does not have an AMD board and I am testing the script on a system that does using putty to access each system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that's putty behavior.
You can use the sed command to replace leading spaces with tab characters:

```
sed "s/    /\t/g" filename
```

The example above replaces 4 leading spaces with 1 tab. Change the number of spaces to suit your needs. If the output looks right, you can save the changes to the original file instead of printing it to standard out:

```
sed -i "s/    /\t/g" filename
```

Answer (score 0):

My fix has been, if I am editing something on Windows which I will run as a script in Linux later, is to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It has a nifty feature; under Edit, you can choose EOL Conversion then change a file from Windows to Linux -or- MacOS EOL formatting!